# Need a generate XSD schema for the following xml?

Tags: xsd

I would like to generate a proper XSD for the following xml. I tried with online conversion but every web-site gives a different output. could you please help me with a correct XSD?

```
<empsts:empTest xmlns:empsts="http://www.empsts.com/schema/empsts"  
xmlns:cm="http://www.empsts.com/schema/common" 
xmlns:deccm="http://www.empsts.com/schema/deccm" 
xmlns:mis="http://www.empsts.com/schema/miscellaneous" 
xmlns:emp="http://www.empsts.com/schema/emp" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.empsts.com/schema/empsts ../idec/empsts.xsd" 
empsts:docType="DEC" empsts:id="01020150609000133" empsts:msgType="EMPSTS">
<empsts:record>
   <emp:payment xsi:type="empsts:empStatusType">
       <empsts:reference>
           <empsts:acctId>ubce</empsts:acctId>
           <empsts:docRefNo>2015021</empsts:docRefNo>
           <empsts:regType cm:type="1">10</empsts:regType>
           <empsts:empSSN>1296238</empsts:empSSN>
       </empsts:reference>
       <empsts:statusInfo>
            <empsts:statusDate>2023-06-31</empsts:statusDate>
            <empsts:statusCode>1</empsts:statusCode>
           <empsts:originalMsgId>EMP2015021</empsts:originalMsgId>
      </empsts:statusInfo>
      <empsts:statusErrorDetails>
           <empsts:statusErrorCodeDetails>8</empsts:statusErrorCodeDetails>
           <empsts:remarks>Follow</empsts:remarks>
      </empsts:statusErrorDetails>
  </emp:payment>
</empsts:record>
<empsts:record>
   <emp:payment xsi:type="empsts:empStatusType">
       <empsts:reference>
           <empsts:acctId>ubce</empsts:acctId>
           <empsts:docRefNo>2015021</empsts:docRefNo>
           <empsts:regType cm:type="1">10</empsts:regType>
           <empsts:empSSN>1296238</empsts:empSSN>
       </empsts:reference>
       <empsts:statusInfo>
            <empsts:statusDate>2023-06-31</empsts:statusDate>
            <empsts:statusCode>1</empsts:statusCode>
           <empsts:originalMsgId>EMP2015021</empsts:originalMsgId>
      </empsts:statusInfo>
      <empsts:statusErrorDetails>
           <empsts:statusErrorCodeDetails>8</empsts:statusErrorCodeDetails>
           <empsts:remarks>Follow</empsts:remarks>
      </empsts:statusErrorDetails>
  </emp:payment>
</empsts:record>
</empsts:empTest>
```

Can someone help me with a correct XSD schema file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a schema from an example XML document in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716620/how-can-i-create-a-schema-from-an-example-xml-document-in-perl)

Comment: Is your goal to ***generate automatically*** or to ***simply create*** an XSD for your XML?   Also, your `schemaLocation` suggests an XSD already exists.  Have you looked for an existing XSD for the `http://www.empsts.com/schema/empsts` namespace at `../idec/empsts.xsd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not possible to generate the schema automatically, because you can not guess optional elements. But as a starting point you can try this transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               elementFormDefault="qualified" 
               attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
      <xsl:for-each select="//*[not(descendant::element())]">
        <xsl:element name="xs:element">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="//*[descendant::element()]">
        <xsl:element name="xs:element">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                <xsl:element name="xs:element">
                  <xsl:attribute name="ref">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xs:schema>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882819/402322). It might be necessary to add the name space requirements manually.

Comment: How to run the xml with the above xsl ? any tool. also need help on the name space as it is confusing and throwing URI exception